# Need to reorganize or recreate index after insert?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, database-administration

I have inserted a million rows into a table(on sql 2000), which already has several million rows in it.
There are indexes on the target table.  It was not dropped before the new insertion.
So, do I have to rebuild or reorganize the target table's indexes, after every new insertion??
Or does SQL server 2000 already perform an auto arrangement of the indexes after the load??

Dbas /Sql specialist please  reply..these indexes are confusing me a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you should reorganize it since after such a huge insertion your indexes will be fragmented.

To check the percentage fragmentation you can do this:-

```
 DBCC SHOWCONTIG
```

or

```
 select i.name,avg_fragmentation_in_percent 
 from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),null,null,null,null) 
 S inner join sys.indexes I on s.object_id=I.object_id and s.index_id=i.index_id
```

Check this [site](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/22/sql-server-difference-between-index-rebuild-and-index-reorganize-explained-with-t-sql-script/)

> Index should be rebuild when index fragmentation is great than 40%.
>   Index should be reorganized when index fragmentation is between 10% to
>   40%. Index rebuilding process uses more CPU and it locks the database
>   resources. SQL Server development version and Enterprise version has
>   option ONLINE, which can be turned on when Index is rebuilt. ONLINE
>   option will keep index available during the rebuilding.

Comment: is it true for sql 2000 as well?

Comment: where can i find whether the fragmentation is great than 40%?

Comment: Yes that is true for SQL 2000 as well!!

Comment: You can run DBCC SHOWCONTIG to check the index fragmentation

Comment: Or you can try this to get the percentage fragmentation details:- select i.name,avg_fragmentation_in_percent from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),null,null,null,null)  S inner join sys.indexes I
on s.object_id=I.object_id and s.index_id=i.index_id

Comment: @user1254579:- Updated my answer as well with both the option to check how to find the fragmentation!!! Hope that works for you!! :)

Comment: thanks ..there is another quetion ..wt is the difference b/w creating a non clustered index on combination of 5 columns and seperate non clustered index for each of these 5 columns?Please answer

Comment: @user125457:- Could you please post another question for this??? This would benefit you more as many other people may answer you in that case. P.S.:- Waiting to see your next question soon!!!

Comment: Thanx a lot and I waiting for your next question. Happy coding!!